# GETTING ITEM.Category from queryset

Tags: html, django

I realized search method. And it works great

```
views.py
def get_queryset(request):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    search_query = request.GET.get('search_item','')
    if search_query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains = search_query)
    context ={
        'queryset': queryset
    }
    print(request.GET)
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

So i want to filter my items by category like search method, but my queryqict is empty. i think because of it is not in input form like a search. how can i realize it.

```
models.py
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('BP', 'BuildingProducts'),
    ('OT', 'OtherProducts'),
)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length = 2,)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length = 1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:''product', kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

Here's the method get_cartegory:

```
 views.py
    def get_category(request):
        queryset = Item.objects.all()
        search_category = request.GET.get('search_item','')
        if search_category:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category__icontains = search_category)
        context ={
            'queryset': queryset
        }
        print(request.GET)
        print(context)
        return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

URLS.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home-page'),
    path('', products, name='products'),
    path('search/', get_queryset, name='get_queryset'),
    path('search/', get_category, name='get_category'),
]
```

home-page.html here's the code for search which works

```
  <form action="{% url 'core:get_queryset' %}" class="form-inline" method="get">
    <div class="md-form my-0">
      <input name='search_item' type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </div>
  </form>
```

home-page.html here's the code which i'm trying to filter category

```
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core:get_category' %}" name="search_item" value="BP"
        method="get">Building products</a>
      <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    </li>
```

Print(request.GET), Print(context) when searching

```
<QueryDict: {'search_item': ['Suka']}>
{'queryset': <QuerySet [<Item: Suka>]>}
```

Print(request.GET), Print(context) when filtering by category

```
<QueryDict: {}>
{'queryset': <QuerySet [<Item: Пена блоки>, <Item: Кирпичи>, <Item: Монтажные шторы>, <Item: Брусчатки>, <Item: Suka>]>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing Django-related here, just plain HTML...

A link is not a form - the 'value' and 'method' attributes in your nav link are not expected for a `<a>` tag and are just plain ignored. If you want to add a querystring to a link, you have to do it manually:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core:get_category' %}?search_item=BP">
   Building products
</a>
```

This being said, you should not use the querystring here but instead [use django's dynamic urls system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) so you have clean urls, ie "/categories/" or something similar.

Also, this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ....
    path('search/', get_queryset, name='get_queryset'),
    path('search/', get_category, name='get_category'),
]
```

won't work - you can't have two url matching the same pattern as there's no way Django would know which one to use, and as a result only the first one will ever be used.